# How to open new tab with manifest 3? (chrome extension)

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

i wanted to make an extention for myself and my friends to easily navigate around websites with an extention but it doesnt work when i click the button

this is my manifest.json code:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name" : "Shortcuts",
    "description": "Shortcut buttons to other Websites!",
    "version" : "0.2",
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["*://www.google.com/*"],
        "css": ["main.css"],
        "js": ["content.js"]
    }],
    "action": {
        "default_icon": {
                "16": "/images/testingbrowserextention16x16.png",
                "48": "/images/testingbrowserextention48x48.png",
                "128": "/images/testingbrowserextention128x128.png"
        },
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_title": "a popup is supposed to come"
    }
}
```

and this is my popup.html code

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function pressmebtn(){
    location.href = "https://www.google.com/";
}
</Script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="black">
    <font color = "white">
    <h1>Shortcuts</h1>
    <input type="button" target="_blank" onclick="pressmebtn();" style="height: 50px;width: 125px; background-color: red; border-radius: 15px; color: white;" value="Google"></input>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 1) Use a separate js file like `<script src=popup.js></script>` 2) Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu.